Ubuntu server crashing from rclone, what could be the problem?
I am using rclone to sync and then check several source and destination directories.
While it is running the Ubuntu Server VM freezes up.
When the Ubuntu Server VM crashes it becomes completely non responsive, the guest agent stops running, I cannot SSH into the machine.
I also cannot shutdown the machine. Only issuing STOP to the VM works in shutting it down, or shutting down the whole ProxMox PVE node, to try and do a more graceful of the VM itself.
It does not seem to be an out of memory issue so far, all indicators of the Ubuntu Server machine seem ok.
It seems like it's not rclone that is freezing the OS, but something related to I/O reading/writing large amounts of data at a very high speed/rate.

I researched how to debug Ubuntu Server the best I can, and here is what I came up with so far:
Ubuntu Server DEBUG information:
sudo cat /var/log/kern.log | grep error
https://pastebin.com/S5VS61Tx
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep error
https://pastebin.com/kM3jxVwb

ProxMox PVE 8.2.4
Ubuntu Server 24.04 (64 bit)

Any help in debugging and fixing this is appreciated!
I have attached some screenshots of the VMs monitoring (click for original size):





Your syslog suggests that an application is crashing, and that the apport crash-reported is creating a .crash file in /var/crash with all the technical details of that crash. Try reviewing that file for clues.

Thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it!
I did not think of this!
Here is the crash report, but I can't make heads or tails of it, it was the only file in in /var/crash/_usr_sbin_agetty.0.crash
Any guidance as to how to read it?
https://pastebin.com/ZC6ZY9ht

That crash file might be unrelated. Look at the creation date.

@user535733, I will have a look and report back as soon as I can!

@user535733, ok, so I ran it again, and it crashed again, but this time the /var/crash/ dir is empty. Where do I go from here, what can I look at for some debug information?
